# Using EclipseLink 2.3.0 from Target

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipselink

I want to use EclipseLink 2.3.0 (as provided with Indigo, resp. the Update Site target provided on http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/) in an Eclipse RCP application.

If I include the EclipseLink libraries specifically in a Plug-In by means of creating a lib folder, stuffing them all in and adding them to the classpath, all the Entities I have in the Plug-In are being found and registered.

If I however switch to using the target distributed EclipseLink Implementation, by adding javax.persistence and org.eclipse.persistence.jpa, the connection to the database is readily built... however NONE of the Entities are found! The occuring message always is:

```
[EL Warning]: The collection of metamodel types is empty. Model classes may not have been found during entity search for Java SE and some Java EE container managed persistence units.  Please verify that your entity classes are referenced in persistence.xml using either <class> elements or a global <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> element
```

My persistence.xml however denotes the respective class, as it is being found when I use the manual libraries! This is rather confusing, any hint on this? :) THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the EclipseLink OSGi examples on the Eclispe wiki for details on how to develop in PDE, how to enable byte code weaving, and an RCP example.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/OSGi

--Shaun

Comment: I've already done that! It did not help me much, as most of the content is not applicable for the new 2.3.0 version.

I found out that it's possible to take javax.persistence from the target, as soon as you take org.eclipse.persistence.jpa from the target however (not from the internal /lib) it stops working!

Comment: It looks like the source for the examples weren't updated to include the new org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.osgi bundle that was introduced as part of the Gemini JPA "upward compatibility" work.  I've updated the RCP example in the EclipseLink subversion repository in both trunk and the 2.3 branch.  Both versions work great with Eclipse Indigo (3.7) for me.